# Python deduce best number among list of lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list, select, rule

```
 A= [[], [2, 3], [1], [1], [3]]
```

I have a list of lists. What I want to do is determine a best number (represent a choice) among the lists. --- a general algorithm to do so

The rules:

1) All the lists are ordered descendingly (**left to right**), so we always choose the number in the earlier sub-list (in this case `[2, 3]`)

2) If there are multiple numbers(can't decided), we keep going down, until  the number appears in the following earliest sub-list. In the case of `A`, both `[1]` does not contain 2 or 3 and as the last item `[3]` contains 3, we decide the best number in `A` is 3.

I all make more examples to be more clear.

```
B=[[5], [0, 8], [0, 8], [0, 8], [1]]
```

The best number is 5.

```
C=[[0, 1], [0, 3], [0], [0], [2]]
```

The best number is 0.

```
D=[[], [3, 6], [3, 5, 6], [6], [1]]
```

The best number is 6.

Anyone has any idea how to write the algorithm... got stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: it is still *very unclear* to me..

Comment: What exactly qualifies a value in the list to be the *best* number?

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Show us what you tried and tell us what doesn't work with you approach.

Comment: *"..All the lists are ordered descendingly.."* no they are not. How do you mean that?

Comment: What are your rules for choosing best number ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the specification is: Take the leftmost number `x` for which the list `[x]` exists?

Comment: Yes, the most left.

Comment: I don't know how to write the code, I have tried use set and extend. Since the algorithm needs to be based on each sub-list, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please don't let the fact that I posted an answer deter you from improving your question. It's still confusing and hard to understand, and it's in your best interest to clarify it as much as possible to get those down- and close-votes undone.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that works fine for all cases and return the list of all first candidates encountered if no choice can be made to separate them.

```
def find_best(list_of_lists):
    i = 0
    while len(list_of_lists[i]) == 0:
        i+=1
    list_containing_candidates = list_of_lists[i][:]
    if len(list_containing_candidates) == 1 :
        return list_containing_candidates[0]
    else:
        if i+1 < len(list_of_lists):
            for next_list in list_of_lists[i+1:]:                
                for candidate in list_containing_candidates[:]:
                    if candidate not in next_list:                        
                        list_containing_candidates.remove(candidate)
                if len(list_containing_candidates) == 0:
                    list_containing_candidates = list_of_lists[i][:]
                elif len(list_containing_candidates) == 1:
                    return list_containing_candidates[0]
        return list_of_lists[i] # ambigous case, entire list of candidates returned



print(find_best([[], [2, 3], [1], [1], [3]]))  # 3
print(find_best([[5], [0, 8], [0, 8], [0, 8], [1]]))  # 5
print(find_best([[0, 1], [0, 3], [0], [0], [2]]))  # 0
print(find_best([[], [3, 6], [3, 5, 6], [6], [1]]))  # 6
print(find_best([[], [3, 6], [3, 5], [6], [1]]))  # 3
print(find_best([[1,3 ], [1, 3], [1,2,3], [1,3], []]))  # [1,3]
```

Comment: Thanks, as I have asked Aran-Fey, if A=[[1,3 ], [1, 3], [1,2,3], [1,3], []], how could it return [1,3]?

Comment: sorry, i've made a little update, i forgot to make a copy of some lists in the previous edit, this one should match your needs : [[1,3 ], [1, 3], [1,2,3], [1,3], []] returns  [1,3]

Comment: Thanks. this should do the work.

Comment: no problem, if you want me to clarify something or discuss possible improvements, just ask !

Comment: I am looking at the code, this is more in line with what I was trying before. I ll ask if I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in three steps:

1. Iterate over the nested list and extract all numbers from single-element lists like `[5]`
2. Flatten the nested list into a list of numbers
3. Iterate over the flattened list until you find a valid number

```
def find_best(choices):
    # make a set of valid output numbers
    valid_numbers = {sublist[0] for sublist in choices if len(sublist) == 1}

    # flatten the nested input list
    flat_list = (number for sublist in choices for number in sublist)

    # find the first number that's a valid output
    return next(number for number in flat_list if number in valid_numbers)

print(find_best([[], [2, 3], [1], [1], [3]]))  # 3
print(find_best([[5], [0, 8], [0, 8], [0, 8], [1]]))  # 5
print(find_best([[0, 1], [0, 3], [0], [0], [2]]))  # 0
print(find_best([[], [3, 6], [3, 5, 6], [6], [1]]))  # 6
```

Comment: Thanks, it's been much clear for me. I ll vote once i can. By the way, do you have any suggestion if there are two same number always exist. Such as A=[[1,3 ], [1, 3], [1,2,3], [1,3], []], it seems cannot return [1,3].

Comment: @ZXie I'm not sure how the "best" numbers are chose in that case. You'll have to be a bit more specific about why `[1, 3]` is the expected output. But the comment section might not be the best place for that. You may want to post another question about that.

Comment: Okay, thanks, It is a strategy I am trying to apply to find out best option among a lot of choices, but it is too long to say it here.